# Can any finite digit of the non-computable function always be a computable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, computability

Can any finite digit of the non-computable function always be computable? If so, does this create a contradiction?

Let $\left\{a_n\right\}$ be a non-computable binary sequence and $f:\mathbb{N^+}\longrightarrow \left\{0,1\right\}$ be a  $n'$th digit of the sequence $a_n$ or $f(n):=\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N^+}}$. Of course, we have no $n'$th digit formula for $f(n)$. Does this imply, any finite digit of the non-computable binary sequence is also not computable ? Otherwise, for any $n\in\mathbb N^+$, if $f(n)$ is computable, this implies $f(n)$ is computable which gives a contradiction. What are the points I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, each individual digit of your sequence $f$ is 0 or 1. 0 is computable, namely by the program "print 0" (which ignores it input). Similarly, 1 is computable. So each individual digit in your sequence is computable.  None of these trivial facts has any bearing on whether the whole function $f$ is computable.

Comment: (+) In other words, we have no $n$th term formula. For this reason $f$ is non-computable?

Comment: Talking about formulas opens a can of worms: What symbols and notations are to be allowed in formulas? Although it's possible to set up notation in such a way that "having a formula" is the same as "being computable", none of the familiar notation systems achieve this. So it's much better to just talk about computability and forget about formulas.

Comment: Okay. can you add little detail to a sentence "whole function f is computable."?

Comment: To say that the whole function $f$ is computable means that there is an algorithm (for example a Turing machine) that, given any natural number $n$ as input, gives $f(n)$ as its output. In other words, the algorithm can answer any of the infinitely many questions "what is $f(n)$?" whenever you give it the relevant $n$.  Note that computability is a nontrivial concept only for questions like this, which have infinitely many instances (one for each $n$). If a problem has only finitely many instances, there's always an algorithm, namely a table look-up.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** A function $\ g:\mathbb{N}^+\rightarrow\{0,1\}\ $ is computable if there exists a Turing machine or equivalent that will eventually return the value of $\ g(n)\ $ when given the value of $\ n\ $ as input.  Suppose $\ h:\mathbb{N}^+\rightarrow\{0,1\}\ $ is non-computable and $\ g:\mathbb{N}^+\rightarrow\{0,1\}\ $ is computable.  Define
$$
a_n=f(n)=\cases{g(n)& if $\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+\ $ is odd,\\
             h\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)& if $\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+\ $ is even.}
$$
Is $\ \left\{a_n\right\}\ $ computable or non-computable?

Comment: So, finite digit of the non-computable function always not a computable?

Comment: No. The function $\ f(n)\ $ defined in my hint is non-computable, but you *can* compute its value for any *odd* $\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+\ $. This is not a contradiction.  Just because you can compute *some* of the values of a function does not mean there is way of dong so for *every* member of its domain.

Comment: Firstly (+1) Thank you for answer. But my question is not about semi-computable functions. The function I am talking about has no computable subset.

Comment: In that case, I have not understood your question and cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: This answer suggests (incorrectly) that the *reason* $a_1,a_{15},a_{37}$ are computable is that they're part of the computable infinite subsequence $(a_n)_\text{odd $n$}$. But note that $a_2,a_{16},a_{38}$ are computable too, even though $(a_n)_\text{even $n$}$ is non-computable. The point here is that any *finite* subsequence of **any** infinite binary sequence is (trivially) computable, and this is so regardless of whether or not the infinite sequence is computable.

Comment: I'm sorry if my "answer" suggests any such thing, since I certainly did not intend it to do so.  Since I'm guessing my final question ( "Can you compute the first, fifteenth or thirty-seventh bits of that binary sequence?") was the main culprit, I have now removed it.  There is also the fact, as I acknowledge in my previous comment, that I do not appear to have properly understood the OP's question.  Consequently, my "hint" does not appear to have been helpful in answering it.